# Generate c# solution template

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I want to create a VS2010 c# solution template generator and I'm looking for free/open tools to achieve this.

An example of what I'm trying to do is a winform application takes project name, namespace and database connectionstring and produce a c# customized solution with my custom classes, namespace and references.

I found those:

- [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Is this the right way to do this? Do you know better tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at project templates. Normally you only get prompted for a project name (used as the solution name as well if creating a solution at the same time).

However the project template system can run code (as seen with C++  and ASP.NET MVC Projects).

There is a lot of information in the [VS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb165067.aspx), but you might find examining project templates that launch wizards useful to isolate the useful bits of documentation.